# Generate pictures in R for use in training algorithms

Tags: r, image, neural-network

I want to train a neural network to count circles on an image by generating thousands of examples. So I need a function to generate a picture with a random number of circles in it.

I have been playing with plots but I guess there must be a better way directly manipulating pixel matrices. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought, it's not an R solution, but ImageMagick can do this. You'd need to generate the command line params - center/radius/colour but that's pretty easy. http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13345#p44929

Comment: `set.seed(123); n= sample(1000, 1); plot( runif(n), runif(n), cex=5, main=bquote( .(n)~ Random~Circles) )` Could also make them of differing diameters by supplying cex with a random sample of sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well throw it out as an answer:

```
set.seed(123)
n= sample(500, 1)  # picks 1 number in range of 1 to 500
plot( runif(n), runif(n), cex=runif(n,1,6),  # Varies size and location
                         main=bquote( .(n)~ Random~Circles) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bioconductor package **[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/)** to draw circles on pixel matrices and save them as PNG files, as demonstrated below.

```
library("EBImage")

set.seed(1)

images = 10   # number of images to generate
size = 500    # X-Y dimensions of images
circles = 50  # max number of circles
rmin = 5
rmax = 25     # max circle radius

xy = size - 2*rmax
rr = rmax - rmin
n = sample.int(100, images)

for (i in 1:length(n)) {
  img = Image(1L, c(size, size))
  x = sample.int(xy, n[i]) + rmax
  y = sample.int(xy, n[i]) + rmax
  r = sample.int(rr, n[i], replace = TRUE)
  for (k in 1:n[i]) {
    img = drawCircle(img, x[k], y[k], r[k], col=0)
  }
  writeImage(img, sprintf("img%.5d.png", i))
}
```

[image: img00001.png]

In case you need filled circles, you can provide the argument `fill = TRUE` to the function `drawCircle`. You can also easily change the image background in the call to `Image`, or vary the circle color with the argument `col` to `drawCircle`. For example, use

```
...
img = Image(0L, c(size, size))
...
img = drawCircle(img, x[k], y[k], r[k], fill = TRUE, col = runif(1, .1))
...
```

for grey circles on black background.

[image]